# Keep a layout of terminals

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a way to "save" a layout of terminals on Ubuntu?
Let's say I have 4 Terminals on a workspace that I'd like to save/restore at will, how could I do this?

**UPDATE:**

- create `gnome-terminal` desktop entry
- edit the preferences and under "Title and Command" be sure to set "Keep initial title" for "When terminal commands set their own titles"
- use `wmctrl` (available on universe repo) to control window

Using the above procedure, one can create as many desktop profiles for gnome terminals and control them by "title" using `wmtrl -R $title_here`.

The profiles are kept under `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may lead you to the answer you are looking for: [Save multiple gnome-terminal layout?](https://superuser.com/questions/72130/save-multiple-gnome-terminal-layout)

Comment: you led me to the answer I was looking for, piece wise :)

Answer (score -1):

Copying my answer from https://superuser.com/a/263249/65499 since it appears you are facing the same issue:

i use a 2-step approach with my `xfce-terminal`. first i open the windows

```
xfce4-terminal --hide-menubar --hide-borders --hide-toolbars -e htop -T hTop
```

and then move them with `wmctrl`

```
wmctrl -r 'hTop' -t 3 wmctrl -r 'hTop' -e 0,927,33,1000,550
```

Comment: you should then link to the post in a comment. just saying.

Comment: tried this stuff, maybe I am doing something wrong but isn't what I am after. thanks anyways.