# What linux terminals support saving layout to what extent?

Tags: linux, terminal, layout, session-restore, window-restore

There is a question [Save multiple gnome-terminal layout?](https://superuser.com/questions/72130/save-multiple-gnome-terminal-layout) it asks if window position, no. of tabs, title etc can be saved across OS reboots, with gnome-terminal.

What are the possibilities with other terminals (Konsole, Terminator, uxterm, lxterminal, etc.) ? Can they restore some of their previous state? How and to what extent?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite terminals **urxvt** and **aterm** support no layout saving or session saving beyond position and title. If urxvt is compiled with Perl, then it supports tabs. This also means it can be scripted to save and restore all kinds of options. Aterm on the other hand, can not do this, but it offers plenty of options through the xresourses and command line flags.